# How to register vault (Hashicorp-vault) as a service in consul (Hashicorp-consul), I am using kubernetes?

Tags: service, kubernetes, consul, hashicorp-vault

I'm running vault and consul as pods in kubernetes, while I'm checking `consul catalog service` it shows `consul` alone.

How can I register `vault as a service`?

I'd tried with the following link, but it didn't work.
https://learn.hashicorp.com/consul/getting-started/services

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For registering vault as a service you will have to do the following steps

1. Create a file and write this `{"service": {"name": "vault", "tags": ["vault-tag"], "port": 8200}}` into it. Name it as `vault.json`
2. Now, enter this command `consul services register vault.json`
3. You can now see that vault is registered as a service
   [image: vault registeration and checking the consul catalog service]

Answer (score 1):

Vault will automatically register with consul when using consul as a backend datastorage. If you are using one of the other storage options you have 2 ways to do it:

### Vault >1.4

If you have vault 1.4 or newer, you can add the following to the vault config to automatically register the vault service in consul

```
service_registration "consul" {
  address      = "127.0.0.1:8500"
}
```

## Vault < 1.4

Assuming you are running vault with https on port 8200

```
{
  "service": {
    "checks": [
      {
        "http": "https://vault1.example.com:8200/v1/sys/health",
        "id": "port",
        "interval": "10s",
        "name": "vault running on port 8200",
        "timeout": "1s"
      }
    ],
    "enable_tag_override": false,
    "id": "vault",
    "meta": {
      "meta": "Vault"
    },
    "name": "vault",
    "port": 8200,
    "tags": []
  }
}
```

**Note** This won't provide the dynamic tags like `active` or `standby` that you get automatically with the other options.
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/configuration/service-registration/consul

Comment: Note also that is it bad practice to use a Consul cluster used as the backing store for a Vault cluster for other purposes including service reg/disco. Deploy a dedicated Consul cluster for that.  And then look at Integrated Storage instead of Consul for Vault which might save you some hosting costs.